# Multidimensional array usage in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Can anyone explain me what the following statement from the below code means..??

`for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                         j++)`

I'm learning Java language and having a very hard time figuring it out..

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
                { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
                { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
                { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
            };
            int searchfor = 12;

            int i;
            int j = 0;
            boolean foundIt = false;

        search:
            for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                     j++) {
                    if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                        foundIt = true;
                        break search;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (foundIt) {
                System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
            } else {
                System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java two-dimensional arrays are implemented is a one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays.

```
for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
```

`arrayOfInts[i].length` means length of the ith row of an arrayOfInts.

```
int[][] a = new int[2][4];
```

This two-dimensional array will have two rows and four columns. This actually allocates 3 objects: a one-dimensional array of 2 elements to hold each of the actual row arrays, and two one-dimensional arrays of 4 elements to represent the contents of the rows.

```
 +-----+    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |a[0] | -> | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] |
 |     |    +-----+-----+-----+-----+    In Java two-dimensional arrays are implemented is a  
                                        one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays -- like this.
 +-----+
 |     |    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |a[1] | -> | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] |
 +-----+    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't really have multidimensional arrays, it has arrays that can contain other arrays. That code takes the `i`th item from the misleadingly named `arrayOfInts`. This item is itself an array of integers, so it's taking the `length` of this array. (That was stored in another array.) So, for example in this code:

```
int[][] array2d = new int[][] {
    new int[] {1},      // stored at array2d[0]
    new int[] {2, 3, 4} // stored at array2d[1]
}
```

the following are true:

- `array2d.length == 2` (The "multidimensional" array contains two other arrays.)
- `array2d[0].length == 1` (The first of which has one element: `1`.)
- `array2d[1].length == 3` (The second has three elements: `2`, `3`, `4`.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no multidimensional array in Java. All there is is arrays of arrays.

`arrayOfInts` is such an array of arrays of ints. So `arrayOfInts[i]` is an array of ints, and

```
for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
```

iterates over every element of this array, i.e. it iterates over all the elements in the array of ints stored at the index `i` of the array of arrays of ints.

You could see it as a big box containing N smaller boxes, each smaller box containg a given number of integers. `arrayOfInt` is the big box. `arrayOfInt[i]` is the `i`th smaller box in the big box. And the loop iterates over every integer in this smaller box.

Comment: `There is no multidimensional array in Java`. In what language there is `multidimensional` arrays, all there is only `array of arrays`.But, it is called as `multidimensional` arrays.There is no difference between `multidimensional arrays` `and array of arrays`.

Comment: [Pascal](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm) has multidimensional arrays, as well as [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177984/what-is-the-definition-of-a-true-multidimensional-array-and-what-languages-sup), for example. I'm sure other languages do have them as well. The main difference is that all the rows in a multidimensional array have the same length, which is not the case in an array of arrays. Another one is that a row may not be null in a multi-dimensional array, whereas it can be in an array of arrays.

Comment: `Multidimensional array` is same as `array of arrays`.in a 2d array having 2 arrays, if all the 1d arrays have equal length, though it will be called`array of arrays`.<br>Else even if one 1d array has different no. of elements than another, it is also `array of arrays`, but it is `jagged`

Answer (score 0):

> > j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length

Cause you array is 2-dimensional, inner element of array will be array to.

So you getting the element(which is array) arrayOfInts[i] and calculates the length arrayOfInts[i].length, in other words:

> > int[] element = arrayOfInts[i];
> >     int length = arrayOfInts[i].length;

Answer (score 0):

Think of arrayOfInts[i][j] as a two-dimensional grid, like a spreadsheet. To help visualize, let's say that [j] represents the column index, and [i] represents the row index.

The explanation is then:

```
// iterate through every column j in the current row i:
for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code , see the words `int [][]arrayOfInts=...`
It is a 2-dimensional array.
2 dimensional arrays are nothing but `arrays of arrays`
It means simply there will be many normal 1-d arrays, and another array having references of each 1-d array.
So, the explanation of line, `for(j=0;j<arrayOfInts[i].length;j++)`is given below:
first, lets give focus to  the words`arrayOfInts[i].length`
I already told you `arrayOfInts` is an array of arrays. So, `arrayOfInts[i]` points to the `i`th array.The word,`arrayOfInts[i].length` returns the length(i.e number of elements in an array) in the `i`th array of `arrayOfInts`.
The loop continues to happen until the `j` is less than then number of elements in the 1d array(less than (don't use equal to) because arrayOfInts[i][0] will be the first element).